# How to filter records with alphabetic order in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

i have Search form which search the Records on user input basis.
there are 3 fields `Firm Name`, `City`, `Country`,
when user type firm name its show the result according to firms name as well as for `City` and `Country`.

here is my Query:

```
Select `firm_name`, `address1`, `address2`, 
    `address3`, `address4`, `cityname`, `phone1` 
from `firms_detail` 
WHERE `firm_name` LIKE '%$firmname%' 
    AND `cityname` LIKE '%$firmcity%' 
    AND `countryname` LIKE '%$firmcountry%'
```

now i have added the field in search form search by Alphabetical order, if user Select Alphadate like A or C and click on Search button so it should the Records of Firm Names Which Start with A or C?

How would i alter my Query? or i should write Separate Query for it?

Comment: `like 'a%$firmname%'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
`firm_name` LIKE '$Alphadate%$firmname%'
```

**OR**

```
Select `firm_name`, `address1`, `address2`, `address3`, `address4`, `cityname`, `phone1` 
from `firms_detail` 
WHERE `firm_name` LIKE '%$firmname%' 
      AND `cityname` LIKE '%$firmcity%' 
      AND `countryname` LIKE '%$firmcountry%'
      AND  `firm_name` LIKE '$Alphadate%' 
ORDER BY `firm_name`
```

Comment: g8 ;) i wrote the same query before but it showed me the warning. but now its working... Thanks bro

Comment: @fzishk: You are always welcome, brother. Feel free to accept this answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: sure but i will allow me after 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results from database and filter through them (which seems a little odd).

Otherwise, you have to perform regular expression on your DB records.

You should tell your query to search for records where the `firmname` equals something that stars with `'C'` or any other letter the user types.

Therefore we have a SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName
```

And then the rest of it:

```
WHERE firmname regexp '^C'
```

As a full statement:

```
SELECT * FROM firmname WHERE firmname regexp '^C'
```

Your key change here is `^` which is a regexp matching the beginning of a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select `firm_name`, `address1`, `address2`, 
    `address3`, `address4`, `cityname`, `phone1` 
from `firms_detail` 
WHERE `firm_name` LIKE '%$firmname%' 
    AND `cityname` LIKE '%$firmcity%' 
    AND `countryname` LIKE '%$firmcountry%'
order by firm_name 

Use order by to order the data based on input.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result in alphabetical order just by using the query below:

Select `firm_name`, `address1`, `address2`, 
    `address3`, `address4`, `cityname`, `phone1` 
from `firms_detail` 
WHERE `firm_name` LIKE '%$firmname%' 
    AND `cityname` LIKE '%$firmcity%' 
    AND `countryname` LIKE '%$firmcountry%'
order by firm_name 
if you want to use alphabetical order by firm_name and so on depending upon what you want to use alphabetical order. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `order by firm_name,cityname,countryname`  at the end of your query.